# Activate venv (Python 3.7.2) for Windows

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I can't activate the venv on my new project (new to Python too),

If I do `python --version`: Python 3.7.2

I created the venv using ' $ python -m venv ./venv ' in my editor (vs code).

and now to activate is where I have a problem,

Attempt 1:

```
$ ./venv/Scripts/activate.bat

error : 'C:\Users\name' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

My user name is formatted from 2 names "name & name" with space between them! Is that a problem? It just show first name and not the second.

Attempt 2:

```
$ C:\Users/name & name/Desktop/ProjectFolder/venv/Scripts/activate.bat

error: 
[1] 15160
bash: C:Users/name: No such file or directory
bash: name/Desktop/ProjectFolder/venv/Scripts/activate.bat: No such file or directory
[1]+  Exit 127                C:\Users/name
```

Comment: Is this in WSL? If so why are you trying to execute the batch files?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using the terminal to navigate to the folder that contains your virtual environment using the change directory (cd) command.  Once there, try typing:

```
source ./venv/Scripts/activate
```

Also, try opening the venv folder and make sure your activate file is in the 'Scripts' folder and not the 'bin' folder.  When I create a virtual environment, I use:

```
source ./venv/bin/activate
```

Comment: $ source ./venv/Scripts/activate.bat
bash: @echo: command not found
bash: rem: command not found
bash: ./venv/Scripts/activate.bat: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `"tokens=2 delims=:"'
bash: ./venv/Scripts/activate.bat: line 4: `for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('"%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com"') do (                                                                   this is the error i have

Comment: Are you in the directory where your venv folder is in your terminal (i.e. the folder that holds your venv folder)?  Try removing .bat also

Comment: its in Scripts ... i open the activate file and on top is # This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*

Comment: yes i`m in the dir inside terminal....i did w/ .bat , this is the error : $ source ./Scripts/activate
bash: ./Scripts/activate: No such file or directory

Comment: Try to cd all the way into the Scripts folder where your activate file is and type `source activate`.  Does that work?  Make sure not to use the '.bat' extension.

Comment: cd venv/   ,    cd Scripts/      :  $ source activate(venv)    i think its working.$ python --version
Python 3.7.2
(venv)
but (venv) is not in front of the name but that is ok i gues

Comment: `source ./venv/Scripts/activate` (not `source ./venv/Scripts/activate.bat`) works for me in git bash on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: source is definitely not windows...

Comment: source neither works in cmd nor in powershell

Comment: Source is not windows, running it in gitbash and getting nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Try `C:/Users/name & name/Desktop/ProjectFolder/venv/Scripts/activate.bat`. Note the exclamation marks and backslash file separator changed to forward slash.

Another way is:

```
C:/Users/name\ &\ name/Desktop/ProjectFolder/venv/Scripts/activate.bat
```

Note the `\` as escape character and backslash file separator changed to forward slash.

And as another option, you can go to directory:

```
cd 'C:/Users/name & name/Desktop/ProjectFolder/venv/Scripts'
```

and than run `activate.bat` from directory.