# Pycharm win32api module install Error: Non-zero exit code (1)

Tags: python, winapi, pip, pycharm, pyinstaller

so i got this problem when I try to: import win32api on my Pycharm project.py code. I got this error: Non-zero exit code (1)

I also tried with pypiwin32 and I still got the same error.

What is strange is when I executed the pip install pypiwin32 command on my CMD the instalation of pypiwin32 worked. But it still doesnt work on Pycharm. Thanks for the help

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're having trouble finding the win32api module.

Don't worry. I will help you solve this issue.

First, if you are using `virtualenv`, please make sure you have activated your environment.

If you don't know how to activate, please refer these links below:

- [How to activate virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604699/how-to-activate-virtualenv)
- [Activate venv (Python 3.7.2) for Windows [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54312543/activate-venv-python-3-7-2-for-windows)

Second, when you create the project, please choose **New environment using Virtualenv**.

Then select **Inherit global site-packages** and **Make available to all projects** and press **Create button**.

This is a screensnap for reference.

[image]

Third, you need to edit configuartions.

Like this screensnap shows below, you need to choose .py file by selecting **Script Path**.

[image]

Finally, after everything is configured, it can work well.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation, it working now. Have a great  day sir!

Comment: @tiberhockey Glad to help.